# Powershell: Does ForEach line read of Get-Content return EOF..?

Tags: powershell

Reading random HTML input files of indiscriminate size I limit read up to 1000 lines or end /html tag. Works fine.

Problem is with small files and when /html tag is missing. I'd like to know when it got to the end.

Question: Is there a some sort of EOF property for that..?

```
$fileContents = (Get-Content -LiteralPath $filePath -totalcount 999)
ForEach ($line in $fileContents){
        $LineNo = $LineNo +1;
        if ((($line.ToLower().StartsWith("</html>"))) -or ($LineNo -gt 999) -or ??? END_OF_$fileContents ???)
            {
                # Do the rest of the processing in here...
            }
        }
```

Couple of days later, here is my final code to handle this (scroll to right);

```
$fileContents = (Get-Content -LiteralPath $filePath -totalcount 999)
ForEach ($line in $fileContents){
        $LineNo = $LineNo +1;
        if ((($line.ToLower().StartsWith("</html>"))) -or ($LineNo -gt 500) -or ($LineNo -ge $fileContents.Count))
            {
                # Do the rest of the processing in here...
            }
        }
```

The idea of doing it this way is to "bail out" of processing massive html files, but still be able to handle a little ones, even if they aren't properly formatted (common in email files).

Comment: $fileContents.Count will return the line count you can then use in your ForEach loop or switch to a straight For loop since you know the number of lines retrieved.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @RetiredGeek I think you're right, that's the only way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for extra EOF file checking. We will use `Get-Content` to handle both the EOF check, as well as the line count (999 lines) check.

We then can use [Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2150063) to parse the file to find the close HTML Tag, and the line number(s).

```
$fileContents = (Get-Content -LiteralPath $filePath -TotalCount 999)

$result = $fileContents | Select-String '<\/html>'

if($result -ne $null -or $fileContents.Count -eq 999)
{
    # Hit Close HTML Tag or file is bigger than 1000 lines

    Write-Host "Hit close tag at line: $($result.LineNumber) or EOF"

    # Do the rest of the processing in here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @HAL9256 normally that works fine, however if the file read is <999 lines and/or the end html tag is missing the subsequent process doesn't run.

Comment: @rangi, ah I see, I modified the answer to handle that case. In this case, we don't need a for loop, and can use RegEx to find the close tags.

Comment: This is correct and we should acknowledge @RetiredGeek spotted it first..! My completed conditional line included above (SO changed response order somehow)

Answer (score 1):

Then scan the file for line count first, use it directly or assign that to a variable, and process as needed.

Refactor of HAL9256 helpful answer:"

```
$filePath = 'D:\temp\Students.html'

Get-Content -LiteralPath $filePath -totalcount (Get-Content -Path $filePath).Count | 
ForEach-Object {
    if ($PSItem.ToLower().StartsWith("</html>"))
    {
        <#
        Hit Close HTML Tag
        Do the rest of the processing in here...
        #>
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, close... see above